# Outlook blocks my PHPmailer but they deny it

Tags: outlook, phpmailer

I use phpmailer to deliver important information to my clients about their interactions with the site, security codes, etc. The mailer uses a gmail account I set up and works just fine emailing other gmail accounts. Hotmail has never worked, and my work outlook account received one or two emails before also going dark.

I emailed the header information to outlook but they state there's no block on the IP and plugging it into their automated system returns google postmaster (which they automatically e-mail instructions to for helping me out. I don't have access to the google postmaster account, so obviously I don't receive them).

My question is what do I do now. Half of my clients use outlook and I need to access them. Outlook customer service has been less helpful than a magic 8 ball and keep referring me back to their smart network data services, which keeps sending info to google postmaster. When I tell them this, they tell me there's no block on the IP and send me the same links. I'm stuck in their loop and just want them to let my e-mails get through!

**EDIT:** 
 I believe it has to do with the PHPmailer, because if I send the e-mail directly from the google account, it gets through:

```
                require "../mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
                    $mail = new PHPMailer;

                    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                          // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication

                    $mail->Username = $outputMail['email'];              // SMTP username
                    $mail->Password = $outputMail['pass'];               // SMTP password
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                    $mail->AddReplyTo("myemail@domain.com");
                    $mail->From = "myemail@domain.com";
                    $mail->FromName = "My Business";
                    $mail->addAddress($email);      // Add a recipient

                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
```

Comment: This is going to be a server- or dns-configuration problem; the answer will have nothing to do with PHP per se. In any case, there's really not enough information here for us (or users at [sf]) to help you.

Comment: The edit didn't change the nature of the problem. There's nothing magic about emails generated by PHPMailer. The problem will be specific to your server, your DNS, or possibly your host. Be aware that the critical difference between (1) logging into gmail and sending and email and (2) sending it programmatically is not typically the software you use to generate the message. It's the IPs, server configuration, and DNS (whether you have appropriate SPF records and such). If you think PHPMailer is at fault, you need to isolate a difference between the good and bad emails relevant to PHPMailer.

Comment: Ok, that's more helpful, thanks.

Comment: Because you added code and this is not *explicitly* about server configuration, I'll reopen it. But please note that you're still asking the wrong questions.

Comment: That's good to know. I'm still new to the site and I got to this point where I didn't know what to ask other than 'OMG help!'. Gotta start somewhere I guess. I'll look up the SPF records you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a LOT of digging, it turns out it was the PHPmailer, so I'll leave this here for anyone that needs it. Outlook / hotmail apparently have an EXTREMELY high spam filter, and mail that has a AddReplyTo or FROM section (as I had above) or does not have an 'unsubscribe' link can be filtered out. Removing that completely solved my problem.

Comment: removing what exactly? the whole $mail smtp configuration? can you show how the code looks like after removing what you removed... im having the same problem